# How do I get mannequins?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

How do I get mannequins in *Animal Crossing: New Horizons*? I’ve talked to Sable every day and she has given me all (I think) of the patterns, but no offers to get the mannequins.

Answer (score 2):

There are no mannequins in New Horizons, as far as I can tell, at least not as a distinct furniture item. However, you can "create" a mannequin by creating a custom design on your NookPhone and then choosing the menu options "Display Here" followed by "Mannequin".  This will create a mannequin that wears a single piece of clothing with your custom design on it.